# Why can't this add another user? Only allows one user to register

Tags: php

```
error_reporting(0);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser = "";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $connection=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $module_ID=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Module_ID FROM Module WHERE Module_Name = '".$_POST['Module_Name']."'");
    $query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($module_ID);

    $result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Attendance (Username, Module_ID, Module_Name, Date, isHere, isLate)
    VALUES ('$_POST[Username]','$query[Module_ID]','$_POST[Module_Name]','$_SERVER[REQUEST_TIME]','Y','N')");

    if (!mysqli_query($connection ,$result)) {
        //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    echo $_POST[Module_Name];
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
    echo $query['Module_ID'];

    mysqli_close($connection);  


}
```

This is the coding and it only allows one user to add to the DB, it cant store any more users. If i try to insert another user it doesn't add to the DB. Any solutions? UPDATE: Still not working, manually adding a user into the user table on the DB. UPDATE: Fixed the issue

Comment: _Please_ don’t use raw POST variables in your SQL statements. Use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please provide you table definitions.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. This doesn't help you, btw `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: try manually adding a user in the database (in phpmyadmin) and if it fails there, it isn't an issue with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `quotes` for key:And always try to capture the error(here mysql),it will help you debugging.

```
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Attendance (Username, Module_ID, Module_Name, Date, isHere, isLate)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['Username']."'","'".$query['Module_ID']."'","'".$_POST['Module_Name']."'","'".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']."','Y','N')");
```

Comment: Does this actually produce something different from what OP already has?

Comment: @JonStirling yes i guess those key the op is using will give the undefined to him.

Comment: If it was actually a syntax error, it wouldn't have run ;)

Comment: @JonStirling try to use this and see:`echo $_POST[Username];`

Comment: @JonStirling You do have syntax error on line 18 of your example.

Comment: @Suchit `echo $_POST[Username];` != `echo "$_POST[Username]"`

Comment: @JamieSterling Try it yourself in your own interpreter.

Comment: @JonStirling i got your point.but i'll suggest to use the quotes one always.

Comment: Just for reference. Here's the relevant [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple). Oh, incidentally I'm not disagreeing with the answers sentiment, though the example is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way because the of all the quotes it would have and just confusing things more.

A perfect example of this is @Suchit's answer.

```
       $username = $_POST['Username'];
       $module_id = $query['Module_ID'];
       $module_name = $_POST['Module_Name'];
       $time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Attendance (Username, Module_ID, Module_Name, Date, isHere, isLate)
        VALUES ('$username','$module_id','$module_name','$time','Y','N')");
```

Comment: Does this actually produce something different from what OP already has?

Comment: Still trying to fix it will not add a user, even though i manually added one in the DB